# different initial viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm building an app where the user can select a project from another `ViewController` and then open a split `ViewController`. I see that I can't set the other `ViewController` as initial, but I've come to with a secondary solution.

I set the split view as initial, and navigate to the fake initial `ViewController` on the `viewDidAppear` method as if it was initial. Then set the selected project in a global variable and close the project page like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

To open the `splitview`.

My question:
Can I use this approach? Will apple approve it if the app works as expected?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

This code is in my AppDelegate.m, what should it be changed to?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UISplitViewController *splitviewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitviewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitviewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
return YES;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UISplitViewController *splitviewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitviewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitviewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
```

How do I reference the self.window.rootViewController to the SplitViewController? So that it doesn't think this viewcontroller will "host" the splitview?

**Edit 3:**

```
// Close the ProjectsViewController and open the selected project
[self presentViewController:_detailViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:_detailViewController];
}];
```

**Edit 4:**

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally

method is linked with button:

```
-(void)selectedProject {
// The user opened a project

// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // assuming your split view controller in storyboard with name "Main" in project's main bundle
UIViewController *splitViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVC"];

UISplitViewController *splitviewController = (UISplitViewController *)splitViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitviewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitviewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

// Close the ProjectsViewController and open the selected project
[self presentViewController:splitViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:splitViewController];
}];
}
```

Showing the projectsPage:

```
- (IBAction)closeProject:(id)sender {
// Show the selectSubjectBanner
_selectSubjectBanner.hidden = NO;

// Save the current subject in case the user edited it
[self saveCurrentSubject];

// Present the ProjectsViewController
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"projectsSegue" sender:nil];
}
}
```

closing the projectspage:

```
- (void)selectedProject {
// The user opened a project

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // assuming your split view controller in storyboard with name "Main" in project's main bundle
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVC"];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

// Close the ProjectsViewController and open the selected project
[UIView transitionFromView:[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view]
                    toView:splitViewController.view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:splitViewController];
                }];
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way by making this, because even you send user to a fake viewController, it will be noticed that you are changing viewController just after another has been loaded

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little better? Why do you say you can't set other view controller as initial? Any view controller can be the initial view controller. Also, a deeper explanation to the architecture your hoping to achieve would help to whomever wishes to assist you.

Comment: Hmm. Do you any idea of a good approach for this issue?

Comment: A split view controller has the be the initial of a story board - think the documentation says it. I want the user to select a project from a view controller and then be sent to a new viewcontroller - the splitviewcontroller.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple's documentation used to say the split view controller had to be the root view controller (not necessary the initial). But that limitation has been removed. [Take a look to the docs your self](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I managed to show the other view controller as initial, but modalling to the split view caused the app to crash

Comment: You can have the split view controller as the root of a navigation controller, then present the navigation controller modally. I've just tried it, and it works. You should subclass the navigation controller and hide the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better to set window's `rootViewController`

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] 
                     setRootViewController:yourViewController];
```

**Edit:** Here is code how to instantiate view controller from storyboard,

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // assuming your split view controller in storyboard with name "Main" in project's main bundle
UIViewController *splitViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVC"];
```

make sure you set Storyboard ID for your view controller in storyboard, Identity Inspector tab, `splitVC`(for example)

**Edit:** So, UISplitViewController is a container view controller itself, thus we can't hold it in UINavigationController, UITabBarController, add as childViewController, .. etc.  And also we can't present it modally, thereby we don't get animated presentation. UISplitViewController should be the window's `rootViewController`. Simplest way to get animated transition between rootViewController and splitViewController is to use UIView's `transitionFromView` class method and visually swap their views, along changing `rootViewController` property. Here is your code edited.

```
- (void)selectedProject {
    // The user opened a project

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // assuming your split view controller in storyboard with name "Main" in project's main bundle
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVC"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitviewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    // Close the ProjectsViewController and open the selected project
    [UIView transitionFromView:[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view]
                        toView:splitViewController.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:splitViewController];
                    }];
}
```

Comment: And then i can modally push to The splitview like a normal viewcontroller? Are tou sure This Will work?

Comment: In this case "yourViewController" becomes initial view controller and appears immediately without animation

Comment: Ok, so I use your solution - works like mine without the animation - and then I can modal from "yourViewController" to the split view?

Comment: Then that seems the most appropriate. But the other code in the delegate setting up the split view - what about it?

Comment: if you are going to use  "-presentModalViewController:animated:" and "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" note that these methods deprecated since iOS 6, instead of those use "-presentViewController:animated:completion:" and "dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:".  good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip!;) but I got some code setting up the split view the the delegate.m - what shall I do about it?

Comment: Am I right You want transition to Split view controller with animation ?

Comment: You want transition from X viewController to Y  and also want Y to become initial view controller,  right ?

Comment: one more question,  saying split view  you mean view controller kind of UISplitViewController ?

Comment: I see, I should set the rootviewcontroller and then modal to the uisplitviewcontroller whenever I open a project, right? And should I let the rest of the code in the delegate stay there?

Comment: what code exactly ?  (btw, make sure that you've checked edited answer)

Comment: Oh, i see - ill try asap I get home;) I need to navigate back to The Project viewcontroller normally during runtime (from a button) - how would I go about that?

Comment: you can do the same with `yourOriginalViewController` just change in the code splitViewController to yourOriginalViewController(any viewController you'd like to present animated and set as root)

Comment: Please see my updated question - I don't quite understand what everything should be changed too :)

Comment: could you plss help me with how I should change my current code (edited question)? Such nice assistance :) - How I can implement the code you posted

Comment: ok, which view controller you want to present/be on screen when app launches ? and are you using storyboards or xibs ?

Comment: i want the projects view controller to be present on launch (not splitviewcontroller) Im using storyboards

Comment: when you select your "project's view controller" in storyboard, in Attributes Inspector tab there is a checkmark "is Initial View Controller", set that

Comment: sat as initial view controller now

Comment: well, now remove code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`  only one line there will be, `return YES;`

Comment: when you run app you see your viewController right ?

Comment: now, for example if you want to show your split view controller on button touch, in button's action method instantiate your splitviewcontroller as you did it before (in appdelegate) and use code in answer edit to show with push animation

Comment: What should the line self.window.rootViewController be? See my question for details. And what shall the presentViewController:splitViewController be? (splitViewController). Are we talking about the master or detailviewcontroller? I haven't specified a custom class for the master detailviewcontroller - the master is linked with the tableview controller

Comment: Still need help with replacing self.window.rootViewController, but is my last edit correct?

Comment: yeah correct,  also check my last edit, is it clear ?

Comment: hmm, tried now - but resulted in NSInvalidArgumentException. I sat "splitVC" as the storyboard ID when clicking in the middle of the Detail View Controller. See what code I used in my last edit

Comment: which line causes that ?

Comment: this: [self presentViewController:splitViewController animated:YES completion:^{

Comment: try to change only FIRST `splitViewController` to  `navigationController`,  `.. presentViewController:navigationController ...`

Comment: I see that we can't present splitViewController with default animation, at least it will work without animation if you remove  `presentViewController` line, right ? but I'll edit my answer later to make transition with animation ..

Comment: Works without animation yes:) -fantastic if you could help me with the animation - really kind:)

Comment: hello again, app works like supposed now without animation - but what do you think about the animation? Got any smart moves?

Comment: are you sure that you copied that code fragment from answer ? `-(void)selectedProject` method

Comment: I changed the code again a little bit, please copy & try once again.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Animation is running! Takes a little time from when I press until it starts, but it works :)

Comment: Sure did! The anim works, but the second time I open ProjectsViewController, the animation isn't there. It's only there the first time :p

Comment: you mean when you get back again to ProjectsViewController and touch button "selectProject"  ?

Comment: Yeah, the second time i press "selectedProject" the animation vanishes

Comment: how you get back, post code for back button's action, I'll check

Comment: instead of `performSegue` instantiate `ProjectsViewController` and navigate to it in same way as in `selectProject` method you did with `splitViewController`. Do it yourself ;)    (make sure you've removed segue from storyboard and set Storyboard ID for ProjectsViewController) good luck!

Comment: Oh yeah, did it on first attempt ;) - now the animation persists

Comment: good! I'm glad to help you, I think you learned at least some new tips in ViewControllers navigation, along solving your problem. Also I recommend you to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html,  good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I have:) i'll read The link u sent - thanks A LOT for your help today! Truly appreciate it:)

Comment: hello again, app works like supposed now - but the animation isn't good if you use landscape as the anim always opens in portrait. Then it doesn't animate the reorientation. Perhaps I should just go with navigating modally to the projects page on the viewDidAppear method if Apple will approve it?

Comment: What do you think? @Seryozha

Comment: Hello, did you try to change animation option parameter to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop` or  `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom` when device in landscape orientation ?

Comment: Hmm, don't think I tried to change it according to the device orientation - but I also liked the modal (sliding up) animation so much, a little uncertain whether I should go with this approach or the first one i thought of - modal to the projectsviewcontroller at viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

You can set any viewcontroller as your inital viewcontroller

You cannot launch a viewcontroller in viewDidAppear method. Thats bad.

Apple will not be rejecting app when considering the app transitions. It up to the developer.

You can set any viewcontroller on top by resetting the rootviewcontroller of window

Instead of storyboard check your logic and launch the necessary viewcontroller from appdelegate. Replace the window rootViewController respectively as mentioned by Seryozha

Comment: I managed to show another viewcontrollerr as initial, but The problem was to modal to The splitview - how can i do This?

Comment: You should create a splitviewcontroller object and then just present it to the viewcontroller. Or just replace the window rootviewcontroller.